# Why is my KendoUI Widget being returned as undefined?

Tags: jquery, razor, kendo-ui, datetimepicker

I am writing some jquery to work with values provided by my KendoUI Widgets for MVC.  I've been following their own documentation but I'm getting problems with widgets returning as `undefined`.  The first place I looked was their troubleshooting and they ask you to confiem all your scripts are in the correct order and there are no duplicate references to jQuery.  I've done this but still getting problems.

The problem with widgets being returned as `undefined` seems to be limited to the kendo date/time picker.

Here is the widget defined in HTML using Razor views.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
  .Name("estDept")
  .Value(DateTime.Now))
```

I have a function that runs when the page loads and also when a specific button is pressed.  The code to get the value is as follows:

```
function voyageTime() {
    var estDeparture = $("#estDept").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
    console.log(estDeparture.value());
};
```

When you first load the page, this code works fine but should you refresh you get an error saying that `estDeparture is undefined`.  I tried adding the code to the document ready function `$(function(){ ... });` which does work but it's not where I want it to live.  So, to test I defined the widget in document ready as a global variable like so:

```
$(function(){ 
    //I missed out var to define a global scope
    estDeparture = $("#estDept").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
    console.log(estDeparture.value());
});
```

When I access the above global variable from my function I get the same undefined error, like it can't pass it to a static function.

What am I doing wrong here and why is a defined widget being returned as undefined all the time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specifically familiar with Telerik's Kendo library, but it sounds like your element(s) might not be being re-registered with the DOM on refresh.  I have had this problem before with updating partial views (which I assume is similar to a Kendo element).  The problem is that when the partial view renders initially, all the DOM elements get registered and so they exist for the corresponding events.  However, after the partial view refreshes, all of the elements in the partial view are "new" and not registered with the DOM events anymore.  The way I overcome this is to write my jquery functions using the "document" object (rather than the specific dom objects).

Partial view:

```
<div id="reloadedWidget">   
    <input id="reloadedElement" type="text" />
</div>
```

For example:
I write something like this (***works after partial refresh***) :

```
<script>
$(document).on('change', '#reloadedElement', function(){ 
    var estDeparture = $(this).data("kendoDateTimePicker");
    console.log(estDeparture.value());
}); 
</script>
```

Rather than writing (***breaks after partial refresh***):

```
<script>
$('#reloadedElement').onChange(function() 
{ 
    var estDeparture = $(this).data("kendoDateTimePicker");
    console.log(estDeparture.value());
}); 
</script>
```

**[Click here for example code](https://github.com/garyscode/disconnected-dom-elements-example)**